# Composing independent traits

Tags: scala, traits

Given two independent traits:

```
trait T1 {
    def x = 42
}

trait T2 {
    def x = 0
}
```

If I try to define a class mixing in these two traits like:

```
class C extends T1 with T2
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error: overriding method x in trait T1 of type => Int;
method x in trait T2 of type => Int needs `override' modifier
class C extends T1 with T2
      ^
one error found
```

Now suppose T1 and T2 have been developed independently, hence no override as they do not override anything. How can C be defined then? Like this:

```
class C extends T1 with T2 {
    override def x = super.x
}
```

?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is known as the [diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem). In Scala there are two ways to solve this:

```
trait T1 {
  def x = 0
}

trait T2 {
  def x = 42
}

class C extends T1 with T2 {
  override def x = super.x
}

class D extends T2 with T1 {
  override def x = super.x
}
```

If you call `new C().x` now, you will get `42` because Scala uses the implementation of the trait you mixed in last. `new D().x` will yield `0` by the way. This means, that in order to solve the diamond problem, you have to define explicitly which implementation you would like to use.

The other way is as follows:

```
trait T {
  def x: Int
}

trait T1 extends T {
  override def x = 0
}

trait T2 extends T {
  override def x = 42
}

class C extends T1 with T2
```

A call to `new C().x` will still yield `42` because T2 is the last trait mixed in. The difference is that you don't have to define `x` in `C`.

Comment: This is interesting.  If the two definitions of `x` in `T1` and `T2` have different types, it seems to be an unavoidable problem.

Is there a clever way in Scala to fix these name conflicts if the types don't match?

Comment: Use my first example and then define `C` as follows: `class C extends T1 with T2 { override def x = super[T1].x }`. Of course, you may also call `super[T2].x`.